# Large nocturnal butterfly with red and black hindwings

Tags: species-identification, entomology

**Location**:

Central Poland, urban environment.

**Size**:

Around 4 centimeters long.

**Time**:

Early July.

**Images**:

[image: hindwings visible]
[image: hindwings hidden]

Answer (score 5):

That is a moth, in the family Erebidae. It is in the genus *Catocala*. Wikipedia has a nice page on Lepidoptera of Poland. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lepidoptera_of_Poland
including all the *Catocala* there.

Comment: It looks a lot like [Catocala elocata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catocala_elocata).